# Being not able to play videos on youtube with selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
    
    
browser=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
browser.maximize_window()
    
 
browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yjO6yfHLcU&ab_channel=TRT%C4%B0zleTRT%C4%B0zleDo%C4%9Fruland%C4%B1") 

browser.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-play-button ytp-button").click()
sleep(2)
```

I can not able to play videos on YouTube with selenium and python. How can I do that?
This is the Error :

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ytp-play-button ytp-button"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a wait / delay there.
Immediately after `browser.get("the_url)` the page is still not loaded, it takes some time, so the element you are trying to click is still not there.
You have to add some delay.
The correct way to do this is to add explicit wait, like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ytp-play-button ytp-button")))

element.click();
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233083/discussion-between-murat-tasci-and-prophet).